# Accessing Airflow Variable in List format

Tags: python, airflow

i have this Variable on Airflow

```
['item_1', 'item_2']
```

then i get the variable

```
my_var = Variable.get('my_var')
```

and then i try to loop it like this

```
for var in my_var:
    print(var)
```

it prints the character one by one.

My question is: how do i access the list value? without printing the character one by one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store it as JSON string then use `deserialize_json=True`

```
my_var = Variable.get("my_var", deserialize_json=True)
first = my_var[0]
```